# Why is $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (a-\frac{1}{n}, b+\frac{1}{n})$ equal to $[a,b]$ and not $(a, b)$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I'm an absolute beginner in measure theory and I have a question, now to prove that $[a,b]$ is a Borel set in measure theory we are ought to prove that the closed set $[a,b]$ is a countable intersection of the open sets,

$$[a,b] = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (a-\frac{1}{n}, b+\frac{1}{n})$$

If (and this is the part that I'm doubtful of),

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (a-\frac{1}{n}, b+\frac{1}{n}) = (a-1, b+1) \cap ... \cap (a, b) \space \space [1]$$

Then why is $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (a-\frac{1}{n}, b+\frac{1}{n})$ equal to $[a,b]$ rather than $(a,b)$ as we can see in $[1]$.

Comment: $a\in(a-1/n,b+1/n)$ for every $n$ so it also belongs to the intersection. Similarly for $b$. To show that $[a,b]$ is Borel however it's faster to note that it is the complement of an open set, and open sets are Borel

Comment: The intersection contains $(a-\tfrac1n,b+\tfrac1n)$ for every natural number $n$, but it does not contain $(a,b)$, since this open interval is not of the form $(a-\tfrac1n,b+\tfrac1n)$ for any $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: notice that $a,b\in(a-1/n,b+1/n)$ for each $n$, hence contained in the intersection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no $(a,b)$ in the above intersection, so expression $(1)$ is wrong. This intersection contains $a$ and $b$ because each of the set, of which we are taking intersection, contains $a$ and $b$, because
$$a-\frac{1}{n}<a\ \forall\  n\in\mathbb N$$
$$b+\frac{1}{n}>b\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb N$$

Comment: I understood your answer and will accept it shortly but excuse my ignorance, isn't $(a-1/\infty, b+1/\infty)$ equal to $(a, b)$ which means it should be in the intersection?

Comment: @BlgKhalil, $(a-\frac{1}{\infty},b+\frac{1}{\infty})$ is not a term of the concerned intersection. All terms are of the form $(a-\frac{1}{n},b+\frac{1}{n})$ for some natural number $n$.

Comment: This is my last question, so $\infty$ in $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}$ refers to the infinte number of intersections and should not substitute $n$ in $(a-\frac{1}{n},b+\frac{1}{n})$? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, we cannot replace $n$ by $\infty$ in any term.